# Copying files from a remote computer on the localhost using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-4.0

I am trying to copy some files from a remote computer on the localhost but the following error message is thrown:

```
[remoteHost_IP] Connecting to remote server <IP> failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the 
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (<remoteHost_IP>:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken
```

In testing purposes I am using the following script:

```
Param([string] $username, [string] $password)

$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,(ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force)

$storage = "\\localhost's_IP\D$\testfile"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName <remote_comp'sIP> -Credential $credentials{ Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\<localuser_memberOFlocalAdministratorsGroup>\desktop\testfile\asd.txt" -Destination $storage -Force -Recurse}
```

Enable-PSRemoting was executed on both hosts and also every host is part of the TrustedHosts list of the other host.

As operating system, I'm using WS2012R2 and the current version of Powershell is 4.0.

Can you please give me some ideas about how i can solve this? Thanks!

**[Edit]**

As I said, I'm working with PowerShell 4.0 (an upgrade to the latest version is not yet possible in my case). Anyhow, I have tried @vonPryz suggestion and now I cannot see any error message but the file is still not copied on the localhost. Here is my code[Add-Content part works fine]:

```
    $sessiona = New-PSSession -Name sesegnon -ComputerName "10.bla-bla" -Credential $credentials

    $any_error = Invoke-Command -Session $sessiona -ScriptBlock {
              Add-Content -Path "D:\path\int.txt" -Value "message"
              Copy-Item -Path "D:\path\asd.txt" -Destination $storage -Force
              $x = $error[0] | Out-String
              return $x    
    }

    Write-Host $any_error
```

Comment: Does interactive `Enter-PSSession` work?

Comment: When you use Invoke-Command to access network resources you should use CredSSP authentication instead of Default.

" CAUTION: Credential Security Support Provider (CredSSP)
 authentication, in which the user's credentials are passed to a remote
 computer to be authenticated, is designed for commands that require
 authentication on more than one resource, such as accessing a remote
 network share. This mechanism increases the security risk of the
 remote operation. "

Full TechNet [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/hh849719.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you have [latest PowerShell version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395) installed , its very simple with a new parameter `-Tosession` or `-FromSession` for Copy-Item cmdlet.

You just need to create a session using `New-PsSession` cmdlet and use that session name as argument to the `-ToSession` or `-FromSession` parameter.

```
#Example
$Session = New-PsSession -ComputerName Server1
Copy-Item -Path <local path of the server1> -FromSession $Session -DestinationPath 'c:\Path'
```

Regards,

Kvprasoon

Comment: Please note this issue with the fromsession and tosession parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40840269